# Fuzzy match words in any order in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What I need to achieve is to match documents based on single field (product name, which consists of basically all possible filter values). I know it is not the most reliable solution, but I only have this one field to work with.

I need to be able to send a search query and the words in that query to be matched in any order to the name field (name should contain all words from the search query). Actually at this point simple `match_phrase_prefix` works pretty well, but what is missing there is fuzziness. Because another thing we need is to allow user make some typos and still get relevant results.

My question is, is there any way to have match_phrase_prefix-like query, but with fuzziness?

I tried some nested bool queries with match, but I don't get anything near `match_phrase_prefix` this way.

Examples of what I tried:

Pretty good results, but no fuzziness:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name.standard": {
              "query": "brand thing model",
              "slop": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Fuzziness, but very limited matches:

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name.standard": {
                  "query": "thing",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                  "prefix_length": 3
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "name.standard": {
                  "query": "brand",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                  "prefix_length": 3
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Using `should` above, I get more results, but they are way less relevant than the ones from first query.

Comment: why not use simple match query with operator and. It supports fuzziness

Answer (score 0):

Above can be achieved by simple [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.standard": {
        "query": "brand thing model",
        "operator": "and" ,//It means all of above 3 tokens must be present in any order
        "fuzziness": "AUTO" // value as per your choice
      }
    }
  }
}
```